# Static Variable in Template Function Doesn't Seem Unique to Template Instance

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++11, static-variables

I'm trying to learn about [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) using C++ along with boost, and the C++11 spec.  However I've run into a problem that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.  I'm following a tutorial here: [Memoization in C](http://programminggenin.blogspot.com/2013/01/memoization-in-c.html) and the tutorial says that you can generalize the memoization of recursive functions using a templates and lambda functions.  The tutorial also lists recursive factorial and fibonacci functions to use with the template.  However, the guide only uses the fibonacci function.

I wrote a test program to see how this all worked and make both a memoized fibonacci AND factorial function in the same run.  Thing is, the memoization template uses a static map to store cached values and it seems like the map isn't unique to each instance of the memoized functions.  Is this expected?  What should I do to make the map unique to each template instance?  Before I started using C++11 features, I had tried to create a template class that accepted a boost function to encapsulate this process.  Would the static map be unique in a template class instead?

**Main Logic for Creating Memoized Functions**

```
// Template function to create memoized versions of recursive lambda functions
template<typename inType, typename outType>
std::function<outType(inType) > memoize(std::function<outType(inType) > foo) {
   return [foo](inType n) {
      static std::map<inType, outType> memo;

      outType ret;
      if (memo.count(n) > 0) {
         cout << "Cache Hit" << endl;
         ret = memo[n];
         return ret;
      }
      ret = foo(n);
      memo[n] = ret;
      return ret;
   };
}

// Recursive lambda fibonacci function
std::function<int(int) > fibonacci_r = [](int n) {
   if (n <= 1) {
      return n;
   } else {
      return fibonacci_r(n - 1) + fibonacci_r(n - 2);
   }
};

// Recursive lambda factorial function
std::function<int(int) > factorial_r = [](int n) {
   if (n == 0) {
      return 1;
   } else {
      return n * factorial_r(n - 1);
   }
};
```

**Logic For Testing Memoized Functions**

```
int position = 7;
cout << "Fibonacci:" << endl;
cout << "Non Memo Fibonacci" << endl;
cout << position << "-> " << fibonacci_r(position) << endl;
cout << "Memo Fibonacci" << endl;
fibonacci_r = memoize(fibonacci_r);
cout << position << " -> " << fibonacci_r(position) << endl;

cout << endl;

cout << "Non Memo Factorial" << endl;
cout << position << " -> " << factorial_r(position) << endl;
cout << "Memo Factorial" << endl;
factorial_r = memoize(factorial_r);
cout << position << " -> " << factorial_r(position) << endl;
```

**Output**

```
Fibonacci:
Non Memo Fibonacci
7-> 13
Memo Fibonacci
Cache Hit
Cache Hit
Cache Hit
Cache Hit
Cache Hit
7 -> 13

Non Memo Factorial
7 -> 5040
Memo Factorial
Cache Hit
7 -> 13
```

At the tail end of the output you can see that the Memo factorial has a cache hit.  However, I don't think it should have only 1 cache hit.  Either way, `7!` isn't 13 and 13 *is* the cache value for 7 under the fibonacci memo lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

> ...it seems like the map isn't unique to each instance of the memoized functions. Is this expected?

you seem to forget that the **instance** wrt to `static` variables is based on the types, not on the value of the parameters. The type `std::function<outType(inType)>` is the same in both cases. Obviously, when there is only one instance you also have only one static `map`.

---

A partial solution could be this:

```
template<typename inType, typename outType>
std::function<outType(inType) > memoize(std::function<outType(inType) > foo) {
   static int i = 0;
   ++i;
   return [foo](inType n) {
      static std::map<int, std::map<inType, outType>> memo;
      auto& m = memo[i];
      outType ret;
      if (m.count(n) > 0) {
         cout << "Cache Hit" << endl;
         ret = m[n];
         return ret;
      }
      ret = foo(n);
      m[n] = ret;
      return ret;
   };
}
```

But note that now each call will generate its own independent `map`. If you do:

```
auto f1 = memoize(factorial_r);
auto f2 = memoize(factorial_r);
```

then `f1` and `f2` will *not* share the same `map`. This also means that if you do this very often, you might end up using a lot of memory.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense.  I did a little bit of extra reading and I understand how function templates are instantiated, i.e. at compile time, see what uses this template function and what types are passed and then make a new function to use.  However, wouldn't every call to the lambda create a new map as well?  Or does the lambda work the same way where it's created at compile time and every lambda that shares it's signature would share the static map?

Comment: @zero298 The lambda's *type* (the closure) exists only once. Each call gives you another instance of this type, but as with functions, the encoded lambda's code is not "copied" into each instance. The code itself is generated only once by the compiler (per `inType`/`outType`, of course).

Comment: Ah, very cool.  I didn't intend on using this in anything really, just as a learning tool.  Good to find out some facets of these things that I wasn't quite clear on.  I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer since it says why it's not working and a good alternative.